# Weak formulation, Variational formulation, Solution of a PDE.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, convex-analysis, calculus-of-variations

Ok, I'm struggling with some basic stuff. My question is: given a PDE are the concepts of a variational formulation and weak formulation the same?

Take a PDE (letting $\phi : \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ say convex)
$$ 
\partial_t u(t,x)=-\nabla_x \phi(u(t,x)),\quad u(0,x)=u_{(0)}(x)\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
A strong solution $u:([0,T] \times \mathbb{R}^d) \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies the above equation for all $t$ and $x$.

Upon multiplication by a test function $\psi$ and integration of \eqref{1} and moving the derivatives onto $\psi$ via integration by parts one can obtain the weak formulation.

$\textbf{Question :}$ My question is sometimes instead of writing down the weak formulation of a PDE an author will claim it has an associated variational formulation, for instance see [this book chapter](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-0348-7893-7_22), where Eq. $(1)$ is the PDE, and eq. $(5)$ is its variational formulation. What does a variational formulation mean? And where does it come from?

Comment: For me, variational formulation means that the PDE is the Euler-Lagrange equation of some functional.

Comment: @CheeHan ahhh, so two names for the same thing : Euler-Lagrange equation and variational formulation. Thanks

Comment: @CheeHan , could you maybe elaborate a bit on the variational formulation. I am new to the subject so for me all I know : start with a PDE with some dissipation property (say of free energy), hence we know the solution will try to minimise the energy functional, the minimal of an energy functional can be found via the E.L equations ( I.e looking at the first variation).

Comment: I think people use the terms weak and variational formulation interchangeably and they often mean the same thing: hit your PDE with a test function and integrate by parts. What you said above is exactly what I meant, though I would personally use the term variational characterisation instead of variational formulation to distinguish it (:

Comment: @CheeHan But wait : Euler-Lagrange equation and variational formulation and weak formulation are not all the same. Weak formulation is exactly what you describe. But Varational formulation I thought would be to rewrite the PDE as say a minimisation problem of some functional? - which is where the E.L equation comes in (since those functions that satsify the E.L equation are exactly those which minimise the said functional).

Comment: My point is that a lot of people use the term "variational formulation" as well when they write down weak formulation. All I'm saying is that unless specified otherwise, variational formulation is the same as weak formulation in general.

Answer (score 0):

a sequence x_n in hilbert space is said to converge in the weak sense if for every  y in space `<x_n,y>  ->  <x,y>`
strong convergence means

> ||x_n-x|| -> 0

strong implies weak, but not the other way around.
take for example:
the space l_2 of sequences which are bounded in norm.
take the sequence of x_n = 1 on the nth place and 0 otherwise.
then this sequence is not even cauchy.

```
||x_n-x_m|| = sqrt(2)
```

for every n,m.

so it has no convergent subsequence.

but, take 
`<x_n-x_m,y>` for all y in l_2:
cauchy-schwartz tells us:

```
<x_n-x_m,y>  <  ||x_n-x_m||•||y|| = sqrt(2)||y||  -> 0
```

as y is a bounded sequence in l_2.

so there is a weakly convergent subsequence.

variational is exactly the weak sense convergence.

Comment: you have completely missed the point of my question.

Comment: No, I haven't i have given you the mathematical basis for why a weakly convegent sequence is strongly convegent. Translate your variational problem to convergence in norm vs. Classical convergence and you will reach the same conclusion.